# Difference between Linear Hydrography and Area Hydrography

Tags: references, hydrography

I am looking at the U.S. Census data and downloading the linear hydrography and area hydrography datasets to add to my first GIS map (I'm a new student).

I am self-teaching GIS, and after a multitude of google searches, I cannot seem to figure out what the difference between linear hydrography and area hydrography is. The description/definition on these on the U.S. Census Bureau website is sparse, as well as Wikipedia and the NOAA website.

Are there reference materials that would tell me the differences between these, as well as exploring more on hydrography as well?

Comment: Is it as simple as the polygon can have a fill and the linear does not for styling in a GIS?

Answer (score 1):

**Linear Hydrography contains linear water features (streams, rivers, etc.):**

"The Linear Hydrography National Geodatabase contains all linear hydrography (rivers, streams, etc.) for the nation. Linear Water Features includes single-line drainage water features and artificial path features that run through double-line drainage features such as rivers and streams, and serve as a linear representation of these features." [- Data.gov 2015 Linear Hydrography National Geodatabase](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2015-linear-hydrography-national-geodatabase)

**Area Hydrography contains area water features (lakes, ponds, oceans, etc.):**

"The Area Hydrography Shapefile contains the geometry and attributes of both perennial and intermittent area hydrography features, including ponds, lakes, oceans, swamps (up to the U.S. nautical three-mile limit), glaciers, and the area covered by large rivers, streams, and/or canals that are represented as double-line drainage. " [- Data.gov TIGER/Line Shapefile, 2016, Series Information for the Area Hydrography County-based Shapefile](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2016-series-information-for-the-area-hydrography-county-based-shapefile)

**The difference between these is representing water features as lines or as polygons.**

When in the quotes there is mention of single line or double line drainage features that means are you representing the river as a single line or as an area bounded by the shoreline on either side of the river. For example, the representing the Mississippi River as a single line might be fine if you're making a map of the entire country. However if you are focusing on just the New Orleans area it will probably make a lot more sense to represent the river as an area.